# QML ComboBox model can't be filled using Javascript using append()

Tags: qt, listview, combobox, qml, listmodel

I'm using Qt 5.15.2 LTS for developing.

Suppose I have following `ComboBox`:

```
ComboBox {
    id: myComboBox

    ListModel {
        id: myModel
    }

    model: myModel
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        text: name
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        myModel.append({ "name": "1", "value": "val1" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "2", "value": "val2" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "3", "value": "val3" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "4", "value": "val4" });
    }
}
```

When compiling my application, I get the following GUI output:

[image: empty ComboBox]

The ComboBox is just empty - however when calling
`console.log("model.count: " + myModel.count)` in `Component.onCompleted`, I get the output `qml: model.count: 4` so the model seems to be filled but somehow the contents are not displayed.

However, when substituting `ComboBox` with `ListView`:

```
ListView {
    id: myComboBox

    ListModel {
        id: myModel
    }

    model: myModel
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        text: name
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        myModel.append({ "name": "1", "value": "val1" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "2", "value": "val2" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "3", "value": "val3" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "4", "value": "val4" });
    }
}
```

I am getting the deserved output:

[image: filled ListView]

According to the [QML ComboBox docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-combobox.html#details), the `ComboBox` should be perfectly fine being populated with a ListModel:

```
ComboBox {
    currentIndex: 2
    model: ListModel {
        id: cbItems
        ListElement { text: "Banana"; color: "Yellow" }
        ListElement { text: "Apple"; color: "Green" }
        ListElement { text: "Coconut"; color: "Brown" }
    }
    width: 200
    onCurrentIndexChanged: console.debug(cbItems.get(currentIndex).text + ", " + cbItems.get(currentIndex).color)
}
```

How come the behaviors differ so much? What do I have to do to fill my ComboBox in a proper way using Javascript?

Comment: I've tested that on Ubuntu using Qt 6.3, it works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I'm using Qt 5.15.2 LTS. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: @folibis out of curiosity: which `QtQuick.Controls` version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `currentIndex` property. This is coming from the documentation:

[currentIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#currentIndex-prop)

> The default value is -1 when count is 0, and 0 otherwise.

My guess is because you are adding the items to the model after the creation of the ComboBox the `currentIndex` keeps its intial value of `-1`, hence nothing is selected. When you open the ComboBox you can see the values, but by default none is selected.

Also another thing I did was to add the [textRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#textRole-prop) property. You should also add the [valueRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#valueRole-prop) property. I've tested it with both Qt 5.15.11 and 6.4.0.

You should read the paragraph [ComboBox Model Roles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#combobox-model-roles).

```
ComboBox {
    id: myComboBox

    ListModel {
        id: myModel
    }

    textRole: "name"
    currentIndex: 0

    model: myModel
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        text: name
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        myModel.append({ "name": "1", "value": "val1" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "2", "value": "val2" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "3", "value": "val3" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "4", "value": "val4" });
    }
}
```

Comment: "When you open the ComboBox you can see the values, but by default none is selected." That's not correct. When setting the currentIndex to 0, I can see the default value, however when clicking the ComboBox, I don't see a dropdown. I've set the `textRole` and `valueRole` as you suggested.

Comment: out of curiosity: which `QtQuick.Controls` version do you use?

Comment: QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Comment: Same here. That's really weird. Apparently this seems to be a problem with my installation if it's working on your side. I'll check that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to change the `delegate` just to display your content. It is enough to set `textRole: "name"`. As a recommendation, it is generally best to separate the UI and non-UI components, so, I have moved the `ListModel` and `Component.onCompleted` to the bottom of the file:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ComboBox {
        id: myComboBox
        model: myModel
        textRole: "name"
    }
    ListModel {
        id: myModel
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        myModel.append({ "name": "1", "value": "val1" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "2", "value": "val2" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "3", "value": "val3" });
        myModel.append({ "name": "4", "value": "val4" });
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAABwHicjY7LCsIwEEX3/YqQlYIU+ljVnd0qWP8g2kGCSSa0qVRK/t0k9IF101mEe+fOmQmXGhtDKlN1/PGK+I+NS1SmQdFGV/YEMkTEVYnyjifsR+uL1wWRnymY2xJrED65eDG3DfTmhgIKQhWTQENgw3vmrQnDf8uXFXb6hUYFysSovBZgwA0u2IjETGtQ9W4Yj7mjCT0Q+maiC86JhBK7P24g0zWZbiWzNZltJfM1mS+kjewXEEp+Fw==)